# Unable to complete "POST" Call successfully through Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm creating a session along with a name and Service URL followed by performing a post request with passing a file(XML file in the form of Dictionary) as a parameter.

But response code is '500 'instead of '200' (i.e. success).

Library Used:

```
Library  RequestsLibrary
```

Snapshot of code used in Testcases section:

```
create session  session  http://myservice.com/method     #(Just an example)
${response}=  Post Request  session  /post  files=${files}
```

> Error: Not getting any error. Moreover Line of Code which has "Post
>   Request" is passing. But the status of response code is "500"
>   (Supposed to be "200").

Comment: please share more information: what lib are you using, what exact error do you get etc.

Comment: Library Used:  RequestsLibrary
Error:              No Error. But status of response is "500" (Supposed to be "200" ).

Answer (score 2):

A 500 response code means your request worked, but that the server threw an error. You need to check the server logs for more information.